# Ajax POST 500 internal error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my ajax call. It gives me the error shown below. I have looked around here and at Google to find the problem, but I did not find a solution. So, I hope someone can the mistake I've made.

`console.log` shows that the variable is working fine. So I know 100% the error is in the ajax call.

```
jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8888 500 (Internal Server Error)
send 
@ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ script.js:61
```

```
if (isConfirm) {
                    var aanhef = $('select[name="aanhef"]').val();
                    var username = $('input[name="username"]').val();
                    var achternaam = $('input[name="achternaam"]').val();
                    var adres = $('input[name="adres"]').val();
                    var plaats = $('input[name="plaats"]').val();
                    var postcode = $('input[name="postcode"]').val();
                    var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
                    var tell = $('input[name="tell"]').val();
                    var where = $('input[name="hidden_email"]').val();
                    }

            console.log(aanhef + ' ' + username + ' ' + achternaam + ' ' + adres + ' ' + plaats + ' ' + postcode + ' ' + email + ' ' + tell + ' ' + where);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'config/save_profiel.php',
                data: { 'aanhef': aanhef, 'naam': username, 'achternaam': achternaam, 'adres': adres, 'plaats': plaats,  'postcode': postcode, 'email': email, 'tell': tell, 'where': where}
            });



$aanhef = mysqli_real_escape_spring($conn,$_POST['aanhef']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_spring($conn,$_POST['username']);
$achternaam = mysqli_real_escape_spring($conn,$_POST['achternaam']);
$adres = mysqli_real_escape_spring($conn,$_POST['adres']);
$plaats = mysqli_real_escape_spring($conn,$_POST['plaats']);
$postcode = mysqli_real_escape_spring($conn,$_POST['postcode']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_spring($conn,$_POST['email']);
$tell = mysqli_real_escape_spring($conn,$_POST['tell']);
$where = mysqli_real_escape_spring($conn,$_POST['where']);
$first = '1';



$updateUser = "UPDATE users SET aanhef='$aanhef', name='$name', last_name='$achternaam', telefoon='$tell', adres='$adres', plaats='$plaats', postcode='$postcode', first_login='$first' WHERE email='$where'";

if ($updateUser) {
    mysqli_query($conn,$updateUser) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: HTTP 500 indicates a generic server-side error. Anytime you see it your first step should be to check your logs. They should contains more detailed error messages that will help you (and us) to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: [13-Sep-2016 15:55:51 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_real_escape_spring() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/save_profiel.php on line 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in a comment above, [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) indicates a generic server-side error. Anytime you see it your first step should be to check your logs.

You did that, and you found the following message:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_real_escape_spring() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/save_profiel.php

That seems to point the way pretty clearly: You've misspelled [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @ReduanKurtaj, we all make mistakes. There's nothing wrong with that. The important thing is for you to learn from this experience: HTTP 500 means to look at your logs, and the log message you find points to the real problem. Good luck going forward!